# cliext::vector and copy constructor

Tags: constructor, c++-cli

```
ref class A
{
public:
    cliext::vector<int> x;

    A(void);
    A(const A^ copied):
        x(copied->x){};
};
```

I have:

> class "cliext::vector<_Value_t>" : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is
>   declared 'explicit'

How to make the vector copy?

Comment: Try `copied->x.Clone()`?

Comment: cliext::impl::vector_impl<_Value_t,_Is_ref>::Clone : number overloads have no legal conversions for 'this' pointer

Comment: Oh well... look up the definition of the `IClonable` interface to figure out how to clone things. I'm just guessing.

Comment: Using the ^ hat for managed types is important.  So is avoiding STL/CLR, it uniquely combines all the worst features of C++ and C++/CLI.  Perf is very, very poor.  Use `List<int>^ x` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, managed reference types must be declared with the ^ hat.  And they must be initialized, that requires using gcnew to allocate GC memory for the object.  So it is:

```
ref class A {
public:
    cliext::vector<int>^ x;

    A() : x(gcnew cliext::vector<int>) {}
    // etc..
};
```

Do note that if you provide a copy constructor then you ought to provide the assignment operator as well, rule-of-three style.  This is rarely needed for reference types unless you give them value semantics like STL/CLR needs.  Otherwise the reason that [perf is so poor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24206/A-look-at-STL-CLR-performance-for-linear-container).  Do strongly favor `List<T>` instead.  A big advantage of having a garbage collector is that you don't have to worry anymore about objects in a collection needing destruction.